# creating div and add divs into it with for loops in for loops

Tags: javascript

i tried to do some artistic stuff with javascript and maths and for this i need some Random html elements in my page.

I create div#mainStage manually in HTML, I want to add div.box 10 times and I want to add 5 divs with different name into each div.box.

I copy my codes sample in here, i just try this loop with create element method but I can not make it work.

```js
outerloop:

  for (i = 1; i < maxboxNum;) {
    var createBox = document.createElement("span");
    document.querySelector("#mainStage").appendChild(createBox);

    innerloop:
      for (var j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
        document.querySelector("span").innerHTML = j;
      }
    i++

  }
```

My HTML Output is;

```
<div id="mainStage">

  <span>4</span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>

</div>
```

Comment: Do you mean add `span`s rather than `div`s?  As your example above is adding `span`s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var maxboxNum = 10;
var mainStage = document.querySelector('#mainStage');
for (var i = 1; i <= maxboxNum;) {
    var createBox = document.createElement('span');
    createBox.appendChild(document.createTextNode(i <= 5 ? 'Span #' + i : ''));
    mainStage.appendChild(createBox);
    i++
}
```

When you call the internal `for` loop, you're not done appending elements to the parent so it runs 5 times (0 + 5 = 4, technically 0 counts as 1 so yeah arrays are weird), so you always get 4 and it will always append to the first element.

The code:

```
createBox.appendChild(document.createTextNode(i <= 5 ? i : ''));
```

Will add a text node to the `span` you created, and if the count is `less than or equal to` it will add the number, else it will just output a blank string.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
for (var i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
  var createBox = document.createElement("span");
  createBox.innerText = i;
  document.querySelector("#mainStage").appendChild(createBox);
}
```

I've moved the `i++` into the loop and removed the inner loop altogether and just set the text when creating the `span`.

Your code above will create 1 span on first loop, then the inner loop runs 5 times populating the same div with 0-4 (hence the 4 there at the end).

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that `document.querySelector("span").innerHTML = j;` will always select the first element, [as the doc specifies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) . If you want to select the n-th span element, you either have to use a CSS selector that does that like [:nth-child](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp) or use the [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) function.